# How to move a dropped item?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

After having dropped an item using `world.dropItem()` or `world.dropItemNaturally()`, how do I move it?

Comment: What do you mean by move it? Dropped items stay still and despawn after 5 minutes if not picked up.

Comment: @MrLore Moving it to another location...

Comment: Yeah but why? Both of those methods let you specify where to drop it, so why are you dropping it where you don't want it to be then moving it?

Comment: @MrLore Because I want to let it move. I mean letting it move by teleporting it to the next point, then to the next, then to the next so it 'floats' to another point. I just need to know to teleport it to another point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`org.bukkit.entity.Item#teleport(Location location)`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Entity.html#teleport%28org.bukkit.Location%29) will allow you to teleport the item to another position. You'd use it like this:

```
final Location dropLocation = new Location(world, x, y, z);
final Location teleportLocation = new Location(world, x + 1, y + 1, z + 1);

final Item dropped = world.dropItem(dropLocation, new ItemStack(Block.anvil));
dropped.teleport(teleportLocation);
```

Though you may need to use a timer to do this, or it may happen too fast to notice.